# Get Type of ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, json, object, activex, typeof

im struggeling a bit with the ActiveXObjects. I'm using JavaScript to Access Applications from the Browser, in this case CatiaV5, the problem described is the same with Outlook and other apps as well. When I watch an Expression via Dev-Tools i get this

[image]

However if I try to access the object through the console or in the Code i only get objects that seem empty. I guess this is because the Object is not in JSON, so I only can access known types. In this case I could access the "Name" directly.
If i do a typeof I get returned "object". Do you know if there's a way to determine the type of object (in this case object HybridShapePointCoord). This would make it alot easier for me to parse the ActiveXObject into a JSON. Otherwise I'd come up with tests for every object to determine what it is, which would be very time intensive. (in this case this would look like)

```
if(currentItem.X && currentItem.Y && currentItem.Z ....){
return 'HybridShapePointCoord'
}
```

Would be great if someone had an idea. Thanks in advance and

Greetings Chris

Comment: Try `typeof obj` or `typeof(obj)` (both the same - choose which pleases you the most)

Comment: typeof just gives you "object" not "object HybridShapePointCoord" sadly.

Comment: What does `obj.toString()` give you? That should (hopefully) show it's an object but also specify its type.

Comment: It doesn't support the method. Probably also because its no common Object. I wonder how the Dev-Tools get the type. If they can somehow recognite it there must be a way